Can someone resolve the error I m facing on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with ROS (Humble hawksbill)
I'm following this video series, ROS2 Tutorials - ROS2 Humble For Beginners, and the ROS 2 Documentation: Humble, for ROS2 installation. I copy-pasted the first six commands mentioned in the documentation and everything was fine. When I entered sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop I got the following error.
robot@robot - hp:~$ sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-paraview : Conflicts: python3-vtk9 but 9.1.0+really9.1.0+dfsg2-3build1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Can someone please guide me? I'm new to Ubuntu and ROS.

It seems that paraview is a conflicting dependency. Try to remove the package and do update & upgrade again. Then try to install humble desktop.
